# Find the nature of the triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Consider a triangle $ABC$ for which $\tan \frac{A}{2} = \frac{a}{b + c}$, where $a = BC, \: b = AC, \:c = AB$.
Then, the triangle is:

**A) equilateral**

B) right triangle with $A = \frac{\pi}{2}$

C) right triangle with $B = \frac{\pi}{2}$ or $C = \frac{\pi}{2}$

D) acute

E) obtuse

All I could do was to eliminate "$A$", which is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option C) is correct by  trig simplification.

By Sine Rule $a$ is proportional to  $\sin A $ with circumcircle diameter as constant of proportionality.

Using shorthand for $ ( s= \sin, c=\cos )$

$$ \tan A/2 = \dfrac{s_{A/2}}{c_{A/2}}= \dfrac{s_A}{s_B+s_C}= \dfrac{2 s_{A/2}c_{A/2}}{2 s_{(B+C)/2}c_{(B-C)/2}} \tag1 $$

since

$$ \frac{(A+B+C)}{2}=\pi/2,\tag2 $$

$$ \cos A/2 = \sin (B+C)/2  \tag3 $$

Plug into 1) RHS, it simplifies to

$$ \dfrac{s_{A/2}}{c_{(B-C)/2}} \tag4 $$

LHS

$$ \tan A/2 = \dfrac{s_{A/2}}{c_{A/2}} \tag5 $$

In RHS of 4) and 5) numerators are same, so equate denominators

$$ \cos A/2 = \cos \frac{B-C}{2} \tag6 $$

For inverse cosine function equality we should have either

$$ \frac{A}{2}  = + \frac{B-C}{2} \tag7$$

or

$$ \frac{A}{2} = - \frac{B-C}{2} \tag8  $$

And further on comes to either $B= \pi/2 $ or $C= \pi/2 $ making it a right triangle.

Comment: Why $\cos A/2 = \cos \frac{B-C}{2}$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I cut short one step... Hope now OK,

Comment: Now everything's clear, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can calculate $\tan \frac{A}{2}$ in terms of $\sin A$ and $\cos A$, and you can calculate each of those in terms of $(a,b,c)$ using the Law of Sines and Law of Cosines. Compare this quantity you get with $\frac{a}{b+c}$.